# Ошибка SyntaxError: Identifier 'descrBlock' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток. Кто может подсказать почему происходит эта ошибка.
Есть товар, у него есть 2 поля https://prnt.sc/zlsyln должно сохранять настройки и выводится на сайте как по умолчанию https://prnt.sc/zlt9fa и https://prnt.sc/zltatl , но пункты не сохраняются. В консоли эта ошибка. Вот кусок кода там где происходит ошибка

```html
function showChildDescription(settings) {
        let descrBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('mount_types_description').item(0),
        descrText = descrBlock.children.item(0), descrBlock = getElementsByTagName('p').item(0),
        selectedParentType = $('[name="wpwp_rimsky_mount_types[]"]').filter(':checked').val();
                

        if (selectedParentType != 'no' && !(typeof selectedParentType === 'undefined')) {
            let mountTypeData = settings.mount_types[selectedParentType],
                selectedChildType = $('[name="wpwp_rimsky_mount_types[child][]"]').filter(':checked').val();

            if (!(typeof selectedChildType === 'undefined') && mountTypeData.hasOwnProperty('extended')) {
                let childMountType = mountTypeData.extended[selectedChildType];

                for (var key in mountTypeData.extended) {
                    if (!mountTypeData.extended.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

                    var obj = mountTypeData.extended[key];
                    if (key == selectedChildType) {
                        descrText.innerHTML = obj.description;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                descrText.innerHTML = mountTypeData.description;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: У тебя в `let` дважды встречается объявление переменной `descrBlock`.

Answer (score 1):

Может разделите выражение на части

```
let descrBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('mount_types_description').item(0);
descrText = descrBlock.children.item(0);
descrBlock = getElementsByTagName('p').item(0);
selectedParentType = $('[name="wpwp_rimsky_mount_types[]"]').filter(':checked').val();
```

У вас левая часть выражения только объявляет, а в правой уже вовсю используется

```js
let a = "проверка";

let b = a, b = "результат на лицо";
```

как надо

```js
let a = "проверка";

let b = a;
b = "результат на лицо";
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот это

```
let descrBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('mount_types_description').item(0),
descrText = descrBlock.children.item(0), descrBlock = getElementsByTagName('p').item(0),
selectedParentType = $('[name="wpwp_rimsky_mount_types[]"]').filter(':checked').val();
```

Заменить на это

```
let descrBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('mount_types_description').item(0);
let descrText = descrBlock.children.item(0);
descrBlock = getElementsByTagName('p').item(0);
let selectedParentType = $('[name="wpwp_rimsky_mount_types[]"]').filter(':checked').val();
```